# react-router-dom's useNavigate() is causing my file paths to get lost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So basically, I have a search bar component where upon submitting the form, I use useNavigate to redirect the page to the path /search/:name. The issue is that when I arrive on this page, the images that work fine on other paths get messed up here. also, if I reload the page, the CSS reset is lost as well.

handleSubmit:

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    navigate(`search/${value}`);
  }
```

App:

```
<div className={styles.app}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        {/* Menu e Search deve permanecer em todas as rotas */}
        <Menu />
        <Search />
        <div className={styles.appMain}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route
              path="/movies"
              element={
                <Catalogue
                  content={content.movies}
                  catalogueApi={content.movies.catalogueApi}
                  slideApi={content.movies.slideApi}
                />
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/tv"
              element={
                <Catalogue
                  content={content.tv}
                  catalogueApi={content.tv.catalogueApi}
                  slideApi={content.tv.slideApi}
                />
              }
            />
            <Route path="/bookmark" element={<Bookmark />} />
            <Route path="/search/:nome" element={<SearchResults />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
```

I tried to check if the path is changing or something like that, but that's not the case. The images have an absolute path, so I also don't see a reason for this to be happening

Answer (score 4):

The only issue I see is that the target path for the `navigate` function should be an absolute path instead of a relative path, e.g. `"/search/:nome"` instead of `"search/:nome"`, so the UI isn't appending to the end of the current path.

Example:

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  navigate(`/search/${value}`);
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve it. The issue was that the paths for the images were not relative to the root. Adding '/ ' before each one fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrielAyres Yeah, that'll do it too. You said "the images have an absolute path" so I didn't mention checking that. Glad it's all working for you now though. Cheers.